# How to add empty row to data.table if nrow=0?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I can easily add an empty row to a data frame by;

```
if(nrow(df)==0){ df[nrow(df)+1,] <- NA }
```

How can I do the same thing to a data.table?

Comment: You may need to show your `df`.  If it is `df <- data.frame()
> if(nrow(df)==0){ df[nrow(df)+1,] <- NA }
> df
data frame with 0 columns and 1 row`

Comment: Growing data.frames or data.tables is a bad idea, as I guess you've heard before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work

```
library(data.table)
# construct an example
dt <- data.table("a", "b")
dt
   V1 V2
1:  a  b
dt <- dt[0L] # could also use dt[-1L] in this case
```

Note that `dt[0L]` will always return a data.table with 0 rows but with the same columns as dt (just learned this thanks to the link from Henrik). The data.frame equivalent is `dat[0L,]`.

Check that it has 0 rows. Programatically, you'd use `nrow` to check as given in the OP.

```
dt
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: V1,V2
```

Now, fill it

```
dt[NA]
   V1 V2
1: NA NA
```

As Henrik points out in the comments below, The `i` argument in data.table's `[` method usually interprets `NA` as FALSE, which would lead to dropping the row associated with this value. We can see this with

```
data.table("a", "b")[as.logical(NA)]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: V1,V2
```

or

```
data.table("a", "b")[(NA)]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: V1,V2
```

However, thanks to Henrik's digging through the data.table code, the authors of data.table built in a special case for the exact syntax of `dt[NA]` to return a single row data.table that is filled with NAs in each column. In this case, they replace the logical NA with the integer version of NA,  NA_integer_.

So, in keeping with proper data types,

```
dt[NA_integer_]
```

is the preferred syntax. Frank mentions in the comments that it is possible to return the same result by replacing NA_integer_ with any positive integer value, so for example

```
dt[1L]
```

will work. Generalizing this insight to any data.table, you can return a single row data.table with NA values with

```
dt[nrow(dt) + 1L]
```

Comment: Very elegant solution!!

Comment: Interesting. In the help text for `i`: "logical `NA`s are treated as `FALSE`." But here `dt[FALSE]` is clearly not the same as `dt[NA]`.

Comment: @Henrik That is strange. I didn't see that in the help file until you pointed it out and `typeof(NA)` returns "logical". It appears that `data.table` is performing a conversion to NA within `[ ]` because `dt[as.logical(NA)]` returns the 0 row data.table.

Comment: Even the simpler `dt[(NA)]`, which forces the evaluation of NA, returns the empty data.table.

Comment: @Imo Seems like it is explained [on line 351-361](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/data.table.R): logical `NA` is changed to `NA_integer_`.

Comment: @Henrik Thanks for digging through the code to find that.

Comment: `x[NA_integer_]` also works on many other types of objects, like `Sys.Date()[NA_integer_]` to get an NA date, and I agree it's the preferred syntax. For the OP's case, though, where the object is empty to begin with, *any* single/scalar integer will produce the desired result, `identical(dt[NA_integer_], dt[123456789L])`

Comment: @Frank That is pretty cool. I guess this is also a way to get a single row data.table with NAs from any existing data.table: `dt[(nrow(dt) + 1L)]`.

Comment: You have to have columns set beforehand tho. With a `data.frame` you can grow an object with 0 rows and 0 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could have been using `rbind` but then number of column should have been known for it:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(id=c(1), Name = c("wow"))

DT2 <- DT[id!=1]

if(nrow(DT2)==0){ 
  DT2 <- rbind(DT2, list(NA, NA))
  }

DT2
#   id Name
#1: NA   NA
```

Comment: You could check the number of columns with `ncol`, then replace `list(NA, NA)` with  `as.list(rep(NA, ncol(DT2)))`.